# What is the variable __cached__ used for?

Tags: python

The variable `__cached__` seems to be automatically initialized in any module.

On any arbitrary module:

```
print(__cached__) # None

__cached__ = 'Hello World!'
print(__cached__) # Hello World!
```

What's the rationale behind pre-initializing this variable with `NoneType` object? If this is meant to be  a reserved keyword then why allow users to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__cached__` is an import-related module attribute. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__cached__):

> [`__cached__`] is the path to any compiled version of the code (e.g. byte-compiled file). The file does not need to exist to set this attribute; the path can simply point to where the compiled file would exist

As for why it's `None` - I guess it's because this attribute must exist, but since there is no compiled version of the code in your case, it's just set to `None` to mean "not applicable".